# Stacked chart Scrolling Issue

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart

I have to use stacked bar and there are below requirements :

1. Bar width should be fixed ( lets say 15px, using pointWidth property)
2. Gap should be maintained between bars irrespective of number of values or Bars.
3. If Chart's Height goes beyond 600 px, need to show scroll ( point #1 and Point #2 should be in place)
   I have achieved Point #1 and #2 ( Adjusting chart's height at run time using some logic basis bar/series count) but facing issue on Point #3 as there is a property
   scrollablePlotArea: {
   minHeight: 400
   }
   which displaying scroll when charts min height is less than 400 but it seems no option to show scroll when height goes beyond to particular limit or say MaxHeight option is missing.

Comment: Hi, please show the demo you working on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/krishnaDhaker/rmv49syf/2/
Now in above link, bars start overlapping as i have not given any height. In Events => load => i am resetting size of the chart which is commented, If you uncomment that line, it start maintaining Bar's height and distance among them but scroll does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Responsive rules should help, you can fit a chart for your conditions. I'm not sure you know that fact
the bar chart is exactly the same as a column chart only the x-axis and y-axis are switched.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      minHeight: 600
    },
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 2,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
  }],
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        minWidth: 600
      },
      // Make the labels less space demanding on mobile
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          scrollablePlotArea: {
            minHeight: 800
          },
        },
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

Live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ae4z53hw/

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.condition

---

It would be better to adjust the width of the columns using use groupPadding, pointPadding and centerInCategory to manipulate.
PointWidth is a value in pixels that can be more difficult to manipulate so that they do not overlap.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false,
    stacking: 'normal',
    groupPadding: 0,
    pointPadding: 0,
    centerInCategory: true,
  }
},
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.centerInCategory

Comment: Thanks. Hope this should fix my issue. To maintain distance between bars, i have to write some code which will calculate height at run time.